# ng-file upload not sending file along with other data

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

i am using angular js frontend along with ng-file module  and laravel backend, and for some reason unknown, ng fileupload doesn't send file along with other form data:
here is my form:

```
<form method="post" name="myForm">


         <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="picFile" name="file"    
         accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" required
         ngf-model-invalid="errorFile">

  <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.required">*required</i><br>
  <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.maxSize">File too large 
      {{errorFile.size / 1000000|number:1}}MB: max 2M</i>
  <img ng-show="myForm.file.$valid" ngf-thumbnail="picFile" class="thumb"> <button ng-click="picFile = null" ng-show="picFile">Remove</button>
        </div>

      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input class="form-control input-lg" id="username" type="text" name="username" ng-model="user.username" placeholder="Name" 
        required
        ng-minlength="6"
        autofocus>

      </div>

      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input class="form-control input-lg" type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" ng-model="user.firstname" placeholder="First Name">
      </div>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" ng-model="user.lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
      </div>


      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary" ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid" ng-click="updateProfile(picFile)" >Update</button>

      <span class="progress" ng-show="picFile.progress >= 0">
    <div style="width:{{picFile.progress}}%" 
        ng-bind="picFile.progress + '%'"></div>
  </span>
  <span ng-show="picFile.result">Upload Successful</span>
  <span class="err" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</span>

        {{picFile}}
    </form>
```

and here is my controller:

```
$scope.getProfile = function() {
  Account.getProfile()
    .then(function(response) {

      $scope.user = response.data;

    })
    .catch(function(response) {
      toastr.error(response.data.message, response.status);
    });
};

$scope.updateProfile = function(file) {
file.upload = Upload.upload({
  url: '/kilo/api/me',
  data: {username: $scope.user.username, file: file },
method:"POST"
});

file.upload.then(function (response) {
  $timeout(function () {
    file.result = response.data.message;
   console.log(file.result);
  });
}, function (response) {
  if (response.status > 0)
    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
}, function (evt) {
  // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
  file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
});
};
```

the above sends only the "username" and leaves the file. please can anyone show me what am doing wrong?

Comment: your code seems fine. could be a backend issue. How do you know the file is not sent? Check the network tab of your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Add `arrayKey: '', headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },`  to your upload object.